# MudTreeViewItem - How to set Activated dynamically?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

```html
<MudPaper Width="350px" MaxHeight="500px" Class="overflow-y-auto" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView Items="@TreeItems" @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue" Hover="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context">
                <Content>
                    <MudTreeViewItemToggleButton @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Visible="@context.HasChild" />
                    <MudIcon Icon="@context.Icon" Class="ml-0 mr-2" Color="@Color.Default" />
                    <MudText>@context.Text</MudText>
                </Content>
            </MudTreeViewItem>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>



<MudText Style="width: 100%" Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">
    <strong>
        <i>Debug</i>
    </strong> Selected item: @(SelectedValue?.Text ?? "no selected value")
</MudText>
```

```cs
public partial class LayersTreeView
    {
        private TreeItemData? SelectedValue;
        private HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();
        public class TreeItemData
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }

            public string Icon { get; set; }

            public bool IsExpanded { get; set; } = true;
            public bool HasChild => TreeItems != null && TreeItems.Count > 0;
            public HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();
            public TreeItemData(string text, string icon)
            {
                Text = text;
                Icon = icon;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".azure", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftAzure));
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".github", Icons.Custom.Brands.GitHub));
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".vscode", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio));
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("content", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument));
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("src", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode)
            {TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
            {new TreeItemData("MudBlazor", Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument)
            {TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
            {new TreeItemData("_Imports.razor", Icons.Filled.AlternateEmail), new TreeItemData("compilerconfig.json", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileImage), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.csproj", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio), new TreeItemData("NewFilesToBuild.txt", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument), }}, new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Client", Icons.Filled.Folder), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler", Icons.Filled.Folder), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Server", Icons.Filled.Folder), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.UnitTests", Icons.Filled.Folder), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.UnitTests.Viewer", Icons.Filled.Folder), new TreeItemData(".editorconfig", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode), new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.sln", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio)}});
            TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("History", Icons.Filled.Folder));
        }
    }
```

I am trying to set the TreeViewItem to become "dynamically selectable".

I want only to allow selecting the ChildViewItem, not the parent. Howerver, the app is frozen when I tried to set `<MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context" Activated="@(!(context.HasChild))">` and select any `MudTreeViewItem`.

How may I have the desired output? Thank you.

Comment: what is the even purpose of using Activated if there is another attribute Selected? isnt selection can be simply done setting this to true?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for the frozen behaviour. It is because the `Activated=true` item can only have one at a time. Setting `Activated=@context.HasChild` violates the "one at a time" rule when there is more than one item having children.

The workaround I found is to use the `@if-else` directive to create `MudTreeViewItem`. Not sure if it is the best/correct way to do so, but it gets job done.

The following is the full solution.

```
<MudPaper Width="350px" MaxHeight="500px" Class="overflow-y-auto" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView Items="@TreeItems" @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue">
        <ItemTemplate>
            @if (@context.HasChild) {
                <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context" Activated="false">
                <Content>
                    <MudTreeViewItemToggleButton @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Visible="@context.HasChild" />
                    <MudIcon Icon="@context.Icon" Class="ml-0 mr-2" Color="@Color.Default" />
                    <MudText>@context.Text</MudText>
                </Content>
                </MudTreeViewItem>
            } else {
                <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context">
                <Content>
                    <MudTreeViewItemToggleButton @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Visible="@context.HasChild" />
                    <MudIcon Icon="@context.Icon" Class="ml-0 mr-2" Color="@Color.Default" />
                    <MudText>@context.Text</MudText>
                </Content>
                </MudTreeViewItem>
            }
        </ItemTemplate>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>

@code {

    private HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();
    private TreeItemData? SelectedValue;
    public class TreeItemData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; } = true;

        public bool HasChild => TreeItems != null && TreeItems.Count > 0;

        public HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();

        public TreeItemData(string text, string icon)
        {
            Text = text;
            Icon = icon;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".azure", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftAzure));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".github", Icons.Custom.Brands.GitHub));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData(".vscode", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("content", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("src", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode)
        {
            TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
            {
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor", Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument)
                {
                    TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
                    {
                        new TreeItemData("_Imports.razor", Icons.Filled.AlternateEmail),
                        new TreeItemData( "compilerconfig.json", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileImage),
                        new TreeItemData( "MudBlazor.Docs.csproj", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio),
                        new TreeItemData("NewFilesToBuild.txt" , Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileDocument),
                    }
                },
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Client", Icons.Filled.Folder),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler", Icons.Filled.Folder),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.Docs.Server", Icons.Filled.Folder),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.UnitTests", Icons.Filled.Folder),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.UnitTests.Viewer", Icons.Filled.Folder),
                new TreeItemData(".editorconfig", Icons.Custom.FileFormats.FileCode),
                new TreeItemData("MudBlazor.sln", Icons.Custom.Brands.MicrosoftVisualStudio)
            }
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("History", Icons.Filled.Folder));
    }
}
```